# TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.Blocksize different from PHP's mcrypt_get_key_size

Tags: c#, php, mcrypt, tripledes

why does (C#)

```
System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.BlockSize
```

and (PHP)

```
mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_TIPRLEDES, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

returns a different result?

Comment: show the results

Comment: php returns `24`, .net returns `64`

Comment: must be `key size` is different from `block size`

Comment: ops, my bad. it should be `mcrypt_get_block_size`. even then, i get `8` from it compared to 64 in c#

Comment: try mo yung other modes, baka iba gamit na mode nung c# (try other modes, c# might be using other default mode)

Comment: c# is using `CipherMode.ECB`

Comment: `Warning`
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Comment: The key size and block size are **not** related,

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The C# [System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.BlockSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.blocksize(v=vs.110).aspx) value is in *bits*, while PHP's [mcrypt_get_block_size()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-block-size.php#116148) returns it in *bytes*.

1 byte = 8 bits; 64 / 8 = 8 bytes

It's the same value, just represented in different measurement units.

Answer (score 1):

1. Encryption key sizes and block sizes are **not** related.
2. DES and thus Triple DES have a block size of 8-bytes.
3. Triple DES has a key size of 168-bits in 24-bytes. There are schemes to use shorter keys such as 16-bytes and duplicate the first 8-bytes to the last 8-bytes, this sometimes called Two Key Triple DES.